# Remove link by ID from JointJS graph?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

JointJS offers methods for removing links from graphs such as [dia.Link.prototype.disconnect](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Link.prototype.disconnect) and [dia.Link.prototype.remove](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Link.prototype.remove)

However, they depend on having access to the link object in the first place. Is there any way to query a JointJS graph (`joint.dia.Graph`) for the link object by ID?

I could manually maintain a JS mapping from ID to link object, but that just sounds tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to any link, you have two options then you can remove them

```
_.each(cellView.paper.model.getLinks(), function(link) {
        console.log(link.id, link.get('source'), link.get('target'))
     })

OR

_.each(cellView.paper.model.get('cells'), function(cell) {
    if (cell instanceof joint.dia.Link) {
       // cell is a link
        console.log(cell.id, cell.get('source'), cell.get('target'))
    } else {
        // cell is an element
        console.log(cell.id, cell.get('position'), cell.get('size'), cell.get('angle'))
   }
})
```

courtsey David Durman himself 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jointjs/cWJAK9gSC-Q

else on graph you can emit an event

```
graph.on('change:source change:target', function(link) {
you can use link.remove()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does **graph.getCell(linkId)** not do what you want?

For example

```
graph.removeCells(graph.getCell(linkId))
```

Comment: `removeCells` accepts an array, it should be rather `graph.removeCells([graph.getCell(linkId)])` or `graph.getCell(linkId).remove()`